# Capitalization of wrestling maneuvers

Tags: capitalization

I am currently writing a fan fiction on Wattpad. The characters meet because they are all employed by the same underground wrestling federation. Should I capitalize the names of wrestling moves, holds, and attacks (e.g., Boston Crab, Camel Clutch, Piledriver, Backbreaker) even if the individual components are not proper nouns?

Comment: Have you looked up other questions about capitalization on this site? They will probably answer your question.

Comment: I think only the promoters capitalize on wrestling.

Comment: Welcome to ELU Stack Exchange. I would look up the terms on a site that has wrestling terminology and see if they are capitalized on the site. Or, if they are fictional moves, do a Google search and look at whether the examples are capitalizes. This is research you should do before you ask the question, then cite in your question. Please check out  the [help topic on how to ask a good question](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info.

Comment: Okay, thanks! @KatherineLockwood yeah I'm new so I'll delete this question

Comment: You don't need to delete it if you do some research, hit a dead end, then edit your question to add what you've learned/not learned. Good luck with the fic!

Comment: Okay thank you so much @KatherineLockwood I'll do that when I get home